# O que é, pra que serve e quando usar Friend?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, vb.net, característica-linguagem

Exemplo de código:

```
Friend Const Public Frind
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Friend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/friend?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é um modificador indicando que aquele membro de um tipo (classe, estrutura, enumeração, delegação, etc.) ou o próprio tipo será visível por todo o [*assembly*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_%28CLI%29) (em geral uma DLL). Ou seja, qualquer membro de qualquer tipo que esteja dentro desse *assembly* consegue acessá-lo. É um `public` mais limitado. O `public` permite que toda a aplicação veja aquilo. Neste caso você controla mais o acesso. É um meio termo entre `private` (só o próprio tipo acessa) e `public`.

Então todos os tipos que são amigos podem acessar este membro. Quem mora no mesmo quarteirão (*assembly*/unidade de compilação) são amigos. Mesmo que você vá distribuir esse *assembly* para terceiros usarem você sabe que a aplicação usuária não poderá acessar os membros `Friend`, apenas o que você compilou junto.

Ao contrário da crença popular (acham que é `private`) por padrão ele é o modificador de visibilidade usado pelo compilador.

Para quem conhece o C# é o mesmo que `internal`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Conceptual.md).