# Qual a utilidade de métodos com modificador "internal"?

Tags: c#, modularização

Em que situação eu usaria um método com modificador `internal`? Há uma razão específica para isso, ou seja, onde um `public` ou `private` não atende ou não?

Isso é que eu tenho aqui.

```
internal void MostrarCadastroFornecedor(string pastrNuCPFCNPJ, int paintWucChamador)
        {
            //Declarações
            ENTDBCORPFornecedor ventCorpFornecedor = null;
...................
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Imagino que saiba para que ele serve. Caso não, respondi sobre ele [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44423/101) (é VB.NET mas é ma mesma coisa). Resumindo, ele determina que aquele tipo ou membro tem visibilidade em toda a unidade de compilação, o *assembly*.

Muitos acreditam que o *default* para tipos quando nada é usado é `private` mas na verdade é [`internal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/7c5ka91b(v=vs.120)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Para membros o mais comum é o `private` mesmo (exceto em enumerações e interfaces, já que faz pouco sentido ter algo `private` nestes tipos).

Você o usa sempre que quer permitir que outros tipos relacionados possam acessar este tipo ou membro mas não quer que toda a aplicação acesse. Por isto determinar o que deve entrar em um *assembly* é importante.

O que é privado é o que está em seu quarto, é só seu. O que é público é o que está disponível para todo mundo, que não há restrição. E o que é interno é o que está disponível para toda sua casa, não é privativo seu, mas é privativo da sua família.

## Tipos

Se estamos falando de um tipo significa que este tipo (uma classe, estrutura, enumeração, etc.) só pode ser acessado dentro do *assembly*. É como se ele fosse um `private` de *assembly*. Mas não confundir com `private` mesmo que só faz sentido se um tipo está dentro de outro tipo, aí este `private` indica que este tipo interno só poderá ser acessado dentro do tipo que o contém.

Normalmente é usado para classes e outros tipos auxiliares que só são necessárias para facilitar alguma coisa que está está dentro deste *assembly*. Você isola estes tipos já que eles não precisam ou mesmo não devem ser acessados pela aplicação diretamente. Muito usado se você usa uma programação baseada em componentes, onde estes componentes cooperam entre si.

Lembre-se que uma classe só deve ter uma responsabilidade. Então você poderá dividir uma operação em diversas classes. Mas nem todas precisam ser acessadas pela aplicação, as demais servem como auxiliadoras para as classes públicas. Então classes com visibilidade interna são usadas quando você tem soluções mais complexas.

Em alguns casos podem ser usados para ofuscação de código e dificultar o acesso indevido.

## Membros

Para todos os efeitos um membro `internal` é um `public`, você deve tratá-lo como algo que pode ser acessado fora da classe. Só que é algo público com restrições.

Ele deve ser evitado sempre que possível em um membro, assim como o `public` deve ser evitado. Evitar não significa não usar, apenas quer dizer que você só deve usar se tiver certeza que esta visibilidade é necessária por alguma razão. Sempre deve-se usar a menor visibilidade possível, ou seja, se der, use `private`. Algumas pessoas consideram que foi um erro usar o `internal` como *default*, deveria ser `private`.

Note que um membro `public` de um tipo `internal` é inerentemente `internal`. Um membro não pode ter uma visibilidade maior que seu tipo.

Você pode querer expor certos membros para outros componentes de um DAL, de um ORM que são importantes para uma manipulação interna, mas estes membros não devem aparecer publicamente no modelo exposto para toda a aplicação. Este é só um exemplo.

Algumas pessoas consideram que esta visibilidade é usada mais do que deveria.

*Frameworks* costumam usá-lo com frequência já que são tecnologias intrincadas e muito depende entre seus membros. Se você navegar pelos [fontes do .NET](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) verá que ele é usado com bastante frequência. Lá faz muito sentido, mas é menos comum em aplicações "normais".

## Seu exemplo

Faça um teste e tente acessar este método em um *assembly* diferente. Não consegue. Veja se este método é chamado em algum outro tipo. Se ele não for chamado, **talvez** você possa mudá-lo para `private`. Digo talvez porque no futuro você pode precisar. Mas pelo nome dele, me parece que ele é necessário em outro pontos.

Olhando o resto do código ele parece ter sido escrito por quem não entende muito como a linguagem funciona e acaba fazendo coisas desnecessárias, por isto eu fico pensando se este método deveria ser `internal` mesmo. Não posso afirmar nada sem ver o todo. Um exemplo de coisa desnecessária:

```
ENTDBCORPFornecedor ventCorpFornecedor = null;
```

poderia ser escrito apenas como:

```
ENTDBCORPFornecedor ventCorpFornecedor;
```

sem nenhum prejuízo.

Alguém poderá dizer que também não causa mal, deixa mais explícito. Mas pra que? Eu talvez aria melhor ainda, provavelmente eu teria feito assim (não sei se é possível já que não vi o código todo:

```
var ventCorpFornecedor = new ENTDBCORPFornecedor();
```

Digo tudo isto porque se tem uma coisa desnecessária, pode ter outras.

## Extra

O que muita gente não sabe é que é possível tornar algo interno para um *assembly* diferente ao que um tipo está definido. Isto é feito com um [atributo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1):

```
[InternalsVisibleTo("OutroAssembly")]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Internal.cs).

## Conclusão

Não se preocupe com performance. É só um questão de organização de código.

Se você tem algo com muito `internal` até que está bem. Pior seria se houvesse exagero de `public`. Claro que em muitos casos alguns desses `internal` seriam melhores como `private`. Mas em geral, se só uma pessoa trabalha com aquele *assembly*, é mais difícil isto causar problemas. O programador consegue ter a disciplina para não usar coisas de outro tipo indevidamente.

Mas note que um sistema que tem muito tipo `internal` pode apenas estar deixando explícito o que já era definido por *default*.

Já membros `internal` raramente são boa coisa, a não ser que tenha um motivo muito forte para isto. Assim como `public` não é boa coisa. Mas todo mundo entende quando um `public` é necessário. Quando estiver pensando em colocar uma visibilidade, tente sempre primeiro `private` que é o *default* para membros na maioria dos casos. Se não der, pense em `protected` para permitir que uma classe derivada possa acessar este membro. Se outras classes relacionadas precisam deste acesso, use `internal`. Se além isto classes derivadas em outros *assemblies* precisam acessar o membro use `protected internal` e se precisar dar acesso a um *assembly* específico use o atributo citado acima. E só se nada disso for possível e precisa de acesso mais livre é que deve "optar" pelo `public`.

Answer (score 7):

Seria usado quando você quer que o método seja usado apenas por classes declaradas no mesmo assembly, semelhante ao `internal class`.

Há também o `protected internal`, que permite que qualquer classe no mesmo assembly acesse o método (ou atributo), além de classes derivadas em assemblies diferentes.

Não imagino uma situação que justifique estes modifiers. Acredito que eles estão mais relacionados com RAD, simplificando algumas tarefas ou estruturação do código.

Referência:

[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Comment: Peguei um sistema para dar manu e tem muita coisa do tipo, muita mesmo. Por isso a pergunta para saber se pode haver ipacto de performance ou não, pelo visto não.

Comment: Quanto à performance pode ficar tranquilo, não há nenhuma. Interessante isso ser usado na aplicação. É muito mais comum em frameworks, como o @bigown disse.

Answer (score -1):

Utilizo para que a DLL de teste unitário consiga testar os métodos internos sem precisar expor os métodos tornando-os públicos:

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyLib.Tests")]

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).