# Declaração de classes em C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, encapsulamento

Em quais outros níveis de acesso posso declarar uma classe em C# além de `public` e `private`. Encontrei esses níveis no [site da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels):

```
protected
internal
protected internal
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23/28595)

Comment: Relacionada: [Modificadores de acesso no C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/28595)

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a utilidade de métodos com modificador “internal”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45386/28595)

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private)

Comment: @Anakin86708 Você fez uma pergunta e colocou o link da resposta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes podem ser declaradas como `public`, `private`, ou `internal` implicitamente se nada for descrito no código.

Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa uma classe sem visibilidade explícita não é pública, ela é interna à unidade de compilação, no caso ao arquivo *assembly*, portanto tudo o que for compilado junto no mesmo arquivo executável a enxerga, mas outras partes da aplicação não, para tornar pública precisa explicitar isto.

Classe privada só faz sentido se ela estiver dentro de uma outra classe o que fará que só esta classe poderá enxergá-la. Sua utilidade é limitada para alguns casos.

A documentação exposta na pergunta não fala sobre visibilidade de classes e sim dos membros da classe. Talvez por confundir esses conceitos esteja difícil entender.

Na verdade quando digo classes na verdade estou querendo dizer **tipos**, usei o termo da pergunta, mas tudo que vale para classes vale para estruturas, enumerações e delegados.

Se quer saber sobre visibilidade de membros a pergunta não é exatamente duplicata porque C# é um pouco diferente.

Existem além dos descritos os membros públicos (`public`) que são vistos por toda aplicação mas com escopo do tipo ou da instância daquele tipo.

Tem os membros privados (`private`) que só são vistos dentro do tipo, seja estático ou não.

O membro protegido (`protected`) já conhecido é como o privado, mas também deixa com que as classes herdadas desta classe vejam este membro. Note que só classes podem ter o membro protegido porque é a única que aceita herança. Obviamente que classes `sealed` não podem se beneficiar de `protected` já que nunca serão herdadas.

O membro `internal` é visto por toda a unidade de compilação (o *assembly*), é um semi-público.

Existe ainda o `protected internal` que é um misto dos dois, portanto o membro pode ser visto por toda unidade de compilação e pelas classes que herdarem dela.

Existe ainda o `private protected` para ter o membro que pode ser acessado de uma classe herdada desde que esteja no mesmo *assembly*.