# Classe private em C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, visibilidade, private

Tenho uma classe `Pessoa.cs` `private`, mas eu consigo chamá-la numa outra classe qualquer, por exemplo eu criei uma classe chamada `Parametro.cs`; consigo instanciar a classe `private` `Pessoa` sem o menor problema. O `private` não deveria não permitir o acesso a essa classe `Pessoa`? Pelo menos a lógica é essa quando se trata de propriedades, por exemplo. Eu não vi diferença entre `private` ou `public` na classe.

Pessoa.cs

```
private class Pessoa
    {
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public int idade { get; set; }
        public decimal peso { get; set; }

    }
```

Parametro.cs

```
class Parametro
    {
        public void PreencherPessoa() {
            Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
            pessoa.nome = "José";
            pessoa.idade = 30;
            pessoa.peso = 80;

            MostrarPessoa(pessoa);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fiz isso só para testar o modificador de acesso private na classe. A classe Parametro não herda de Pessoa.

Comment: @HeyJoe, só me confirma uma coisa, as duas classes estão no mesmo escopo certo? As duas estão no mesmo Projeto. Se você tentar chamar a classe "Pessoa" fora do projeto que você está, ela dará erro, certo?

Comment: ah, então o private só serve se for fora do projeto? Fiz o teste aqui.

Comment: Você consegue criar a classe Pessoa dentro de Parametro, pois as duas foram criadas no mesmo arquivo. Crie as duas em arquivos separados e não irá mais conseguir instanciar.

Comment: Exatamente o que o perozzo falou eu ia responder agora, evite criar classes dentro do mesmo arquivo.

Comment: Entendi. As classes estão no mesmo projeto, então elas pertencem àquele projeto, por isso uma tem acesso a outra, mesmo sendo private. Mas as propriedades do tipo private pertencem àquela classe, por isso mesmo que as outras estejam no mesmo projeto não as enxergam. Escopo!

Comment: Isso mesmo HeyJoe, para você não deixar que sua classe seja instanciada mesmo estando no mesmo projeto, você precisa deixar o `Construtor` `private`.

Comment: Não confunda projeto com arquivo. Projeto é o todo: classes, componentes, bibliotecas, a solution em si. No seu caso, sim, as classes estão no mesmo projeto, mas no seu caso tu consegue acessá-las porque estão no mesmo arquivo. O correto, conforme falado anteriormente, é criar cada classe em seu arquivo separado.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238098/69359

Comment: Duplicata não falta! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private)

Comment: @perozzo quando você fala arquivo, você está se referindo ao arquivo da classe: Pessoa.cs por exemplo? Se for isso, elas estão em arquivos diferentes, Pessoa.cs e Parametro.cs

Comment: @HeyJoe isso! O correto é separar os arquivos mesmo.

Comment: Mas já estava assim e estava sendo possível instanciá-la. Só quando eu tentei fazer a instância em outro projeto que não foi permitido por ser private.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic você poderia apontar onde fala sobre classes privadas nessa pergunta que acha que é duplicata? Mais ainda no contexto do C# que é beeem diferente do Java. E porque esse casos específico está respondido lá? Alias, você tem errado bastante em escolher duplicatas, e até aí tudo bem, porque todo mundo por errar, mas parece que você escolhe fechar duplicata dependendo de quem respondeu, e escolhe qual a duplicata ou não colocar como duplicata clara, dependendo que quem respondeu na original. Isto não é bom para o site.

Comment: @Maniero talvez tenha clicado errado e não vejo motivos para tanto e também acho exagero o que você disse sobre as duplicatas e perseguição, mas, que aqui no site tem https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237931/declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-classes-em-c/238098#238098 e mais https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156804/como-funcionam-as-propriedades-no-c e essa como complemento https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private como duplicata da pergunta. Se achar que não é duplicata as duas anteriores tudo bem!

Comment: @Maniero se quiser além do mais eu removo a duplicata que eu indiquei que como lhe disse não foi intencional e sim escolhe na lista talvez clicando no lugar errado...

Comment: @HeyJoe eu estava lendo sua pergunta e percebi uma informação que não bate, se você colocar private na classe ela não é acessível de maneira nenhuma, porque o padrão das classes são `internal` se não for colocado nenhum modificador. As sua classe Pessoa não deve ser acessivel por causa do modificador .. a mensagem é `CS0122 'Pessoa' is inaccessible due to its protection level`
 no minimo estranho nem compila a aplicação e você tem razão de perguntar isso.

Comment: @Virgilio Novic Fiz duas classes Pessoa.cs e Parametro.cs; coloquei Pessoa.cs como private só para teste, se era possível fazer o acesso a ela, dentro do mesmo projeto é possível acessá-la pela classe Parametro, por exemplo. Não ocorreu esse erro que disse. O meu problema era não saber que as classes pertencem àquele projeto assim como as prop. pertencem a sua classe.

Comment: @HeyJoe tem alguma coisa que não bate, porque eu também fiz o teste e não funciona! é estranho como já disse.

Comment: @HeyJoe A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 2):

`private` não é um tipo. Ele é um modificador de acesso. É um atributo que determina onde aquele tipo ou membro de um tipo pode ser visível. Mas visível só onde? Nesse código o tipo `Pessoa` está dentro do que? Ele deveria ser privado a que?

No caso [só pode ser visível dentro de outra classe ou estrutura](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers).

Mas se a classe não está dentro de outra classe, ele pode ser visível dentro de tudo, ou seja, de privado não tem nada, é só uso errado, por isso não viu diferença. Na prática você pode fazer fora da classe, mas ainda será um detalhe de implementação da outra classe do arquivo.

Classes privadas são usadas apenas para implementação interna, nunca para uso geral. Só detalhes que não fazem parte do contrato do tipo pode ser privados.

Por isso que eu sempre falo que não pode aprender vendo o resultado, e sim tem que aprender vendo o fundamento que leva a aquele resultado, até para saber se é coincidência ou não. Só porque funcionou deste jeito não significa que está correto. É um luta inglória. Mesmo pessoas que eu já passei várias vezes esse tipo de coisa, ainda continuam aprendendo do jeito errado.

Comment: Pessoa.cs e Parametro.cs fiz o teste e coloquei Pessoa como private, mesmo assim em Parametro.cs consigo instanciar Pessoa. Essa foi a minha dúvida.

Comment: De fato, era o que eu pensava, mas como vi os comentários, e até achei que fazia um certo sentido e tem linguagens que são assim mesmo, eu confiei na minha intuição e editei e coloquei uma ressalva do arquivo (já retirada), De fato a documentação é muito explícita quanto ao fato de só valer dentro de um tipo, e especificamente `class` e `struct`, já que os outros tipos não faz sentido. Portanto todos os comentários que falam disto na sua pergunta estão errados. Curiosamente eles possuem *ups* e esta resposta não. Lição: nunca confie na sua intuição, mesmo se você for experiente.

Comment: Bom, o Richard Willian estava correto, dentro do mesmo projeto consigo instanciá-la, em um outro projeto não. Mas os outros estavam errado quanto as classes serem do mesmo arquivo, pois não são.

Comment: A sua resposta ficou um pouco complicada para mim. rsrs Quanto a sua pergunta "ele deveria ser privado a quê?" eu só fiz um teste, é que eu tinha notado isso uma outra vez (de que eu poderia instanciar uma classe private) e achei estranho, porque seguindo a lógica das prop. private, eu não deveria poder acessá-la.

Comment: Claro, ao projeto sem dúvida, mas não porque ela é privada propriamente dita, é porque é `internal`. Sim, está declarada `private`, porém é óbvio que isto é uma visibilidade menor que `internal` então ela nunca será vista em lugares onde `internal` não pode ser visto. Só pode ser visto em outros projetos e for declarado como `public` que é mais do que `internal`. `internal` é a visibilidade padrão, e indica o *assembly* (ou projeto, usando a terminologia errada). Você já colocou uma propriedade fora de uma classe? Se não, como pode usar a mesma "lógica"? Minha pergunta continua valendo.

Comment: Eu não compreendia que a classe pertence a tal projeto como uma prop. private pertence a sua classe. Mas agora eu compreendo.

Comment: Resumindo, minha dúvida era "por que eu posso acessar uma classe privada por uma outra classe qualquer sendo que as prop. private eu não posso?", eu não soube formular bem a minha dúvida. Eu simplesmente não sabia dessa questão da classe pertencer ao projeto assim como as outras. Vou fazer uma comparação, veja se está correta: o projeto seria uma classe, as classes seriam suas propriedades.

Comment: Minha dúvida permanece, você achava que pertencia ao que então?

Comment: Achava que não pertencia a nada, eu simplesmente não tinha conhecimento disso, por isso a confusão. E a minha comparação está correta: o projeto seria uma classe, as classes seriam suas propriedades?

Comment: eu pensava que o private iria negar o acesso àquela classe assim como o private nega o acesso a uma propriedade ou a um método.