# Visibilidade de membros de uma classe

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, private, public, protected

Atributos de uma classe são membros private por *default*?

Métodos são funções ou operações membro `private` por *default*?

Um membro privado de uma classe pode acessar um membro público dentro da mesma classe?

Atributos de uma classe podem ser acessados pelas entidades declaradas no mesmo *spacename* por *default*?

Answer (score 2):

[Atributo não é o que você está pensando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101).

Campos são `private` por padrão nos tipos de C#. Métodos são `private` também. Assim como todos os outros membros de uma classe ou estrutura. Mas em interfaces e enumerações o padrão é `public`, até porque foram feitos para expor membros públicos mesmo, e no caso de `enum` nem tem como ter outro tipo de visibilidade.

Um membro público pode ser acessado de qualquer parte da aplicação, incluindo a própria classe toda. O que precisa ter cuidado é com relação a membros da classe e da instância. Um membro de classe não pode acessar diretamente um membro da instância. Veja mais em [Uma classe é uma instância?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/514777/101). [Também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257817/101).

[Entenda `namespace`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101) (e não *spacename*) para ver que não faz sentido o acesso de outras entidades porque ele é só um sobrenome e não algo que agrupe as coisas e dão privilégios especiais.

O que pode ser acessado fora da classe e que não é público (estes podem ser acessados em todo lugar) é o que for [declarado com `internal`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45386/101), mas é sobre visibilidade no mesmo *assembly* (pacote de código) e não o `namespace`. Existem alguns outros atributos de visibilidade que permitem mais acesso, mas acho que não vem ao caso aqui, vai complicar muito, primeiro se acostume com o básico, já tem muito conceito novo e correção do que aprendeu errado.